# What is the value of $g(\pi)$ if $g(x)=\int_{\sin x}^{x^2}(1+t^2)dt$?

Tags: calculus

What is the value of $g(\pi)$ if $g(x)=\int_{\sin x}^{x^2}(1+t^2)\,dt$?

How do you use the average value theorem to solve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean $g(x) = \int_{\sin x}^{x^2} (1+t^2) dt$? If so, directly carry out the integral and plug in.

Comment: How do you "carry out" the integral?

Comment: You can do $\int (1+t^2) dt$ with the power rule. Then use fundamental theorem of calculus with bounds $\sin x$ and $x^2$. then plug in $x=\pi$ (or just calculate $\sin x$, $x^2$ when $x=\pi$ and calculate the integral in that case).

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean. Can you please work it out for me? I'm having a lot of difficulty with this problem and I have a test on it tomorrow.

Comment: If $g(x)$ is given by some expression involving $x$, then $g(\pi)$ is given by taking that expression and replacing $x$ everywhere with $\pi$. Try it!

Comment: Well I get that last part where you substitute pi back in but how does the average value theorem contribute to this?

Comment: I don't know --- I don't know what "the average value theorem" is (maybe it's what I usually call the Mean Value Theorem?) --- but it seems to me that any theorem here is overkill.

Comment: Yes. It's the mean value theorem.

Comment: Solve it your way and show me your work so I can understand what you're talking about...?

Comment: But I've told you what my way is --- you're asking for $g(\pi)$, and you get it by replacing $x$ with $\pi$ everywhere there's an $x$ in the formula you have for $g(x)$. Everywhere you see $x$, put in $\pi$, instead. Please, just do it, and see what you get!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\int_{\sin x}^{x^2}(1+t^2)dt=(t+\frac{t^3}{3})|_{\sin x}^{x^2}$

$=x^2+\frac{x^6}{3}-\sin x -\frac{\sin^3x}{3}$

$g(\pi)=\pi^2+\frac{\pi^6}{3}-\sin \pi -\frac{\sin^3\pi}{3}$

$=\pi^2+\frac{\pi^6}{3}$